Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile)
I am encountering an error when trying to build my Maven project. The build fails with the following error message:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project Blinknotes: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]

Here's the full error output:
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project Blinknotes: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException


i want to deploy my springboot app on heroku by cli but i encounter above error .
here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rajbhut.blog</groupId>
    <artifactId>Blinknotes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Blinknotes</name>
    <description>this is backend apis for notes app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
            <version>1.36.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

i tried:
Verified JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables point to the correct JDK 19 installation.
Ran mvn clean install and mvn clean install -X for debug logging.
Cleaned local repository with mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
How can I resolve the invalid flag: --release error during the Maven build process? Is there a specific configuration or step I am missing?

Are you sure Java 9+ is used? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-release.html

The error message invalid flag: --release tells me you are not using a JDK higher than eight... Try mvn --version and show the output here? Also remove the maven-compiler-configuration from your pom file because that is already provided by the spring-boot-starter-parent...

In cli when I run git push heroku master it start building and shows no openJdk specified and then openJdk 1.8 will be installed this is i get

C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\javarepo\Blinknotes\BlinkNotes_backend>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.7 (8b094c9513efc1b9ce2d952b3b9c8eaedaf8cbf0)
Maven home: C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\apache-maven-3.9.7-bin\apache-maven-3.9.7
Java version: 22.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22

i got solution i just change this in  my pom.xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
   
            <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.13.0</version>  <configuration>
    <source>17</source>  <target>17</target>  </configuration>
</plugin>


Remove the maven-compiler-plugin configuration... the <jave.version>17</java.version> is sufficient...

thank you very much it take around 10 hr to find it
